# Counting distinct dates from two columns in a single SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-columns

I've been reading through the solutions of similar problems posted here, but none seem to resolve my particular issue.

I currently have a table (CT_JOINED) that includes three columns: an identifer column (TUMOURID), a date column (AVCT_DATE) and another date column (OPDATE).

As an example, the columns for two IDs look as follows:

```
ID, AVCT_DATE, OPDATE
1, 06-APR-13, 06-APR-13
1, 06-APR-13, 14-JUN-13
1, 06-APR-13, 22-JUN-13
2, 03-APR-14, 10-DEC-15
2, 03-APR-14, 31-DEC-15
```

What I'm attempting to do is create a column that is equal to the number of unique dates per ID. So the result for ID 1 would be 3 and the result for ID 2 would be 3.

I have attempted a count of distinct values across the two columns, but this does not provide the answers above (it instead reports values of 3 and 2 respectively):

```
select TUMOURID, COUNT(DISTINCT(AVCT_DATE || OPDATE)) AS COUNT 
FROM CT_JOINED
GROUP BY TUMOURID;
```

The same thing happens if I try and do the same in a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE CT_DISTINCT AS (
SELECT TUMOURID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TUMOURID, AVCT_DATE, OPDATE
FROM CT_JOINED)
GROUP BY TUMOURID
);
```

I'm at a loss. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT TUMOURID, COUNT(DISTINCT d) AS cnt
FROM (select TUMOURID, AVCT_DATE AS d
      FROM CT_JOINED
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TUMOURID, OPDATE AS d) sub
GROUP BY TUMOURID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot the data and then use `count(distinct)` or remove duplicates along the way:

```
select tumourid, count(*)
from ((select tumourid, avct_date as dte
       from ct_joined
      ) union -- intentional to remove duplicates
      (select tumourid, opdate as dte
       from ct_joined
      )
     ) t
group by tumourid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to avoid duplicate date & just use `count(*)` :

```
SELECT tumourid, COUNT(date)
FROM ((SELECT tumourid, avct_date AS date
       FROM ct_joined
      ) UNION
      (SELECT tumourid, opdate 
       FROM ct_joined
      )
     ) t
GROUP BY tumourid;
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers below work like a charm with a few tweaks to also account for rows with null values. For instance:

```
SELECT TUMOURID, COUNT(*)
FROM ((SELECT TUMOURID, AVCT_DATE AS DTE
       FROM CT_JOINED
       WHERE AVCT_DATE IS NOT NULL
      ) UNION
      (SELECT TUMOURID, OPDATE AS DTE
       FROM CT_JOINED
       WHERE OPDATE IS NOT NULL
      )
     ) T
GROUP BY TUMOURID;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: If you do `count(date)` then you don't need to use `is not null`.